# <script type='text/javascript'> Meaning please

Tags: javascript, html

I have been asked to write an essay on some code which iv never seen before, one part I am struggling with is this:

```
<script type='text/java-script'>
```

Is it some kind of thing embedded into java script or something else?

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) is always useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this works as below :

```
<script type='text/java-script'>
     //javascript code goes here

</script>
```

this only tell the compiler o the browser or whatever that the code or script in between the scripts tag is a javascript.